# How to generate a random number in the constructor of a class in C#

Tags: c#, methods, random, constructor

I know that it is not a good practice to call a method in the constructor of a class in C# but I stuck on something strange. My problem is that when I create an object of my class I need to assign a field in my object with a random number.

for instance

```
class RandomNumberHandler
    {
        private int randomNumber;
        public RandomNumberHandler()
        {
            this.randomNumber = GenerateRandomNumber();
        }

        private int GenerateRandomNumber()
        {
            return (new Random()).Next(3000) + 1000;
        }
    }
```

In my case I need a four digit number. I thought of generating the random number in the class where I am creating the object and passing it as a parameter to the constructor but generating a random number in the other class does not seem a very good idea either because I am trying to achieve strong cohesion for my classes. I am doing this for a "High quality code" course in my university and I am looking for the best approach. Any ideas how to do this are welcome :)

Comment: It's not a good practice to call a **virtual** (including abstract) method **of the object being constructed** in a constructor. Calling methods is fine, and indeed normal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off: **there is nothing wrong with calling non-virtual methods in the constructor**. Where did you read that there was? (Note: calling *virtual* methods *can* be a problem; it is not an automatic no-no, but you need to watch what you are doing very carefully).

As an aside, it seems wasteful to generate a new `Random` instance every time `GenerateRandomNumber` is called. You can extract the `Random` instance to a field to fix that:

```
class RandomNumberHandler
{
    private readonly Random random = new Random();
    private int randomNumber;

    public RandomNumberHandler()
    {
        this.randomNumber = GenerateRandomNumber();
    }

    private int GenerateRandomNumber()
    {
        return this.random.Next(3000) + 1000;
    }
}
```

But this raises another question: if `GenerateRandomNumber` is only called once in each instance's lifetime (in the constructor), then it doesn't make sense to create a new `Random` for each object. So the next logical step is to make `random` be `static`. This means that `GenerateRandomNumber` can also become `static` (and indeed, it has to):

```
class RandomNumberHandler
{
    private static readonly Random Random = new Random();
    private int randomNumber;

    public RandomNumberHandler()
    {
        this.randomNumber = GenerateRandomNumber();
    }

    private static int GenerateRandomNumber()
    {
        return Random.Next(3000) + 1000;
    }
}
```

Comment: Who knows... these teachers always have to impose their opinions of how things should be done.  I just always go with the flow for the grade.

Comment: There are some considerations to calling *virtual* methods in a constructor though.

Comment: Possibly he is confused about virtual methods.

Comment: @Kirk, @Eric: Sure. But the point is to get the OP to express that in his own words so that he can improve his understanding.

Comment: @Jon, perhaps.  But this statement (in bold no less), "there is nothing wrong with calling methods in the constructor" strikes me as wrong or at best incomplete.

Comment: @Kirk: You 're right on that. I changed it a bit and added a note about calling virtuals.

Answer (score 4):

This code will work okay - except that you'll likely get the "same" random number if you call it in quick succession.

You could, of course, easily work around that by using a static random number (with a lock for thread safety if you're using multiple threads), such as:

```
class RandomNumberHandler
{
    private static Random random = new Random();
    private static object syncObj = new object();

    private int randomNumber;
    public RandomNumberHandler()
    {
        this.randomNumber = GenerateRandomNumber();
    }

    private static int GenerateRandomNumber()
    {
        lock(syncObj)
            return random.Next(3000) + 1000;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 as while it's similar to two other answers, its the only one that's thread-safe.

Comment: @Jon: When I posted it, it was the only version that was using statics ;)

Answer (score 1):

[Random number generator only generating one random number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-not-working-the-way-i-had-planned-c)

Short answer: You should use same Random instance across all `Next()` calls.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any cohesion there by just wrapping the Random class inside of another class named RandomHandler.  Personally, I think thats awkward.  If you need a brand new completely random number then just call Random().Next(3000) or whatever inside of the constructor like you said.

Answer (score 0):

If you lift the `Random` instance as a static field and make the `GenerateRandomNumber` static, you can call it in the declaration of the `randomNumber` field:

```
class RandomNumberHandler {
  private static Random random = new Random();
  private int randomNumber = GenerateRandomNumber();

  private static int GenerateRandomNumber() {
    return random.Next(3000) + 1000;
  }
}
```

Or more simply (and less readable):

```
class RandomNumberHandler {
  private static Random random = new Random();
  private int randomNumber = random.Next(3000) + 1000;
}
```

Although it doesn't look like you're calling a method in a constructor, if you look at the generated CIL, you'll find out that you are.

Also, if you care about thread-safety, take a look at this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/02/19/9434171.aspx).