# random number in constructor c#

Tags: c#, random, constructor, class-constructors

I am a student taking an introductory programming course in line with game development.  One of my assignments calls for me to define a players attack damage inside of the constructor.  I want the damage to be random, but no matter what I do I get back the same number.  This is a test I made to see how I can get this number to be random.

```
class MainChar
{
    public static Random random = new Random();
    public int Atk;        

    public MainChar()
    {
        this.Atk = random.Next(11);
    }

    public void h()
    {
        while (Atk != 10)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Atk);

        }
    }
}
```

I'm creating a new instance of MainChar in my main program, and running h().  I get a repeating list of the same number instead of random numbers between 1 and 10.  Any ideas?

P.S. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422141/how-to-generate-a-random-number-in-the-constructor-of-a-class-in-c-sharp) was useful, but could not answer my question.

Comment: Ask yourself: how many times do I observe the variable changing?  Now, in how many places do I change the variable?  Do you see a connection between those two things?

Comment: Also, here is some good advice for new programmers. Believe me, you do not want to be asking StackOverflow every time you have a bug in your program. Learn your craft! http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: you are calling random.Next only once in your constructor, hence nothing changes.

Comment: Thank you both, this clarifies my issue.  Eric, I greatly appreciate you sharing that article.  I'll be sure to give it a read to help prevent asking simple questions like this when avoidable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the method `h()`, the `while` forms an infinite loop if the `atk!=10`. so you need to specify an exit condition there to break the loop; you can use like this:

```
public void h()
{
    while (Atk != 10)
    {
        this.Atk = random.Next(11);                   
    }
    Console.WriteLine(Atk);
}
```

Now you will get a random number between 0 and 11 and is not `10` in the console

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question.  I was not thinking logically when i placed my this.Atk = random.Next(11); Line

Answer (score 0):

if you want to continue with a random number until it generate a breaking condition or number, you can modify the h() func as:

```
public int Atk;
public static int max = 100;

public void h()
{
    while (Atk != 10)
    {
        this. Atk = random.Next(max);
        Console.WriteLine(Atk);
    }
}
```